# Replacing old 4-way switch

Tags: electrical, wiring, multiway-switch

I have a old 4-way switch whose toggle broke and now needs replacing (see attached).  My problem is I can't figure out the wire mapping.  All 4 wires are yellow.  I guess the ones on top are for 1 3-way switch and the bottom for the other, so I could keep the top for the brass screws on a new 4-way.  Am I making this too complex?  Never replaced a 4-way before.  Thx.

[image: 4-way switch pic]

Comment: Where in the world are you located? That doesn't look like a US switch, or it's a very old one, so knowing your location would help figure out how to wire it.

Comment: That could end up being trial and error. Label all the wires (top left, bottom right, etc.) and take another picture before you disconnect anything. All of them are travelers from 3-ways, so nothing catastrophic should happen.

Comment: Can you post some photos showing the wiring in the back of the box please?

Comment: @Freeman,  He said "4 way"  so it's North America somewhere.

Comment: More than likely original with the house.  This is Chicago-land, house built in 1958.

Comment: How many wires connect to the switch not including a ground?  Before you do anything Mark the wires so you know what screws they attach to it can help if a mistake is made

Comment: If you need to add a visual, you can [edit] your question.

Comment: @FreeMan -- that's what's called a *Despard* system switch most likely -- these were an early form of North American modular gang device that used individual switches/receptacles mated to separately supplied yoke straps, for up to 3 devices/gang

Comment: Wow, @ThreePhaseEel, thanks! Learn something new hear nearly every day.

Answer (score 2):

"all 4 wires are yellow" -> an electrician after my own heart!  Those are my preferred colors.

Here is how 4-ways are wired.

[image]

As you see, the yellow wires (yours actually are that color) come from 2 different places. A pair of yellows comes from one place, and a pair of yellows comes from another place.

Your setup will be in conduit, since nobody makes yellow-yellow-red cables... and much of Chicagoland requires metal conduit.  (that's why there are no ground WIRES; the metal conduit is a superb ground).

So it's as simple as identifying the two pairs.  That's easy because each pair will be in a different pipe.  Hook up the 2 black screws to one pair.  It's downhill from there.

---

If they're all in one pipe, then yikes. The installer should have done something to mark them as pairs.  Look for black and brass screws on the old switch.

Worse comes to worst, if you have to decrypt this, make a test apparatus. Lop the plug end off a $2 extension cord, and plug a night light into it. Simple night light, not a smart light-sensor job.  Split the wires for about 8" and strip the ends. Mark the ribbed wire white and the non-ribbed wire black.

Illegally attach the white wire to the metal of the junction box, i.e. by abusing a mounting screw.  Connect the black to one of the yellows.  (all with the power off, of course).

Turn the power on, and see if the light lights.  Then run around and flip 1 switch at a time, checking in between every switch throw.  If that light comes on in certain switch positions, you have identified a supply-side yellow.  Turn off power and do it all again with the other 3 yellows to identify the other supply-side yellow.  Now, mark those two with black electrical tape for next time!

Comment: The night light trick will fail if the circuit is on a GFCI. Which isn't super likely, but I think worth mentioning just in case.

Comment: Thx so much for the diagram and details!!  Yes, there are 2 pipes coming in with 2 sets of yellow wires in each.  What's a bit confusing to me, and that's probably because I have never worked with a switch like this, is that the wires in each pipe alternate the connection.

Comment: Sorry, I'm a newb to this forum so still figuring posting things out.  I made a pic with visual aids but can't figure out how to comment with a pic.  Regardless, by "alternate" I meant that from pipe1, wires connect to the top-front and bottom-back screws, relative to the original pic.  Pipe2 wires connect  to the top-back and bottom front screws.  But unless I hear otherwise I'll put a new switch in with yellow wires from the same pipe on matching screws.

Comment: @manassehkatz yeah, but it's a successful failure, since the GFCI trip will indicate the same information as a lit light (i.e. you got the right wire).

Comment: @Dave "top-front and bottom-back screws" there's your trouble right there.  In the 3-way and 4-way world, screw *positions* mean nothing and are different on every switch, I swear!  It's all about the color, or on older switches, the labeling. Also certain miswirings can be partially functional.

Comment: *Look for black and brass screws*, +1 ... Except even that's not foolproof; I've had 3-ways with two different color traveler screws, and the common the was same as one of them. 'Trial and error', described, +1. - Does it matter on a 4-way if a single set of travelers is reversed?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming all four yellow wires are travelers, here's how to handle it. You'll need some sort of tester (preferably a contactless "hot" tester)

1. Turn the power off and disconnect your switch. Then nut the four wires off for now
2. Turn the power back on
3. Determine which of your three-way switches is still making the travelers hot
4. Find which of the yellow wires is hot and mark it
5. Go back to the switch from Step 3 and flip it
6. You should now have a new wire that is hot. Mark it.
7. Turn the power off
8. The wiring diagram for your switch should tell you which screws get the incoming hot wires. Hook the two remaining wires up in the remaining screws. Don't worry about matching colors if the instructions get specific.